# Создание эмулятора с большим объемом mock данных

Tags: android, непрерывная-интеграция, эмулятор

Что имеется: дженкинс на удаленном сервере, на котором по триггеру стартует эмулятор и проходятся тесты android apk.

Необходимо: Для теста сбора данных о пользователе, эмулятор нужно наполнить огромным объемом данных разного типа: контакты, смс, история звонков, события в календаре, картинки, музыка, прочее. Приложение выдает кредиты и данная информация критична для нейронной сети в RISK engine. Но вот как можно загрузить такой объем информации в эмулятор? Или может уже есть готовые эмуляторы с большим объемом mock данных? Реальные устройства для повторяемого теста на удаленном сервере не вариант.

Comment: О, верной дорогой идете товарищи. То-то вашу нейронную сети вытащат, разломают и будут потом кредиты получать с высоким рейтингом. Одумайтесь!

Comment: 1 - она на бэкэнде. 2 - проект уже живет достаточно давно, новое приложение не увеличило количество собираемых данных, просто у старой версии никакого тестирования нормального не было в принципе. Ну а риски продумываются теми кто такие заказы делает, и там вовсе не с "вытащат" проблем воз

Comment: То есть вы тестировать будете по сути лишь забор-отправку данных?

Comment: на стороне приложения по сути да, регрессию на разных версиях андроид, скорость сбора информации, обработку случаев когда клиент не дал пермишен на какой либо участок итп